# Azure DevOps/VSTS database and production bug fixes

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

We are currently in the process of setting up VSTS CI/CD to an azure webapp with 3 different stages. Production, Beta, Alpha. But we are facing two issues:

- 1. Database deployment, We are using Azure SQL Server but deploying the database in the pipeline is a problem. The best solution I have so far is to use a Database Project in VS housing the DDL but this means developers must work on the database through VS and doesn't work as well as SSMS. Are their any alternates?
- 2. Production bug fixes. If we require hot-fixes on the production environment then the team breakdowns the pipeline (deploying directly into the production project), as it takes too long to swap the environments and check if everything is okay. Is there a way to deploy change sets directly to the production and mark it as an hot-fix deployment? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - VSTS supports Azure SQL database deployment using DACBAC or SQL scripts, either can be generated from SQL Server Management Studio.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-dacpac-sqlpackage?view=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-database-sqlscripts?view=vsts

2 - You could consider:

- Using build tags to trigger new release process that deploys directly production, by tagging a build with something like `direct-to-prod` and then setting on the deployment trigger. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/vsts/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts.
- Using a separate environment in your existing release that has a manual trigger. i.e. you need to run it manually.

Also calling out that maybe it is a good opportunity to review the currently process build/release process. Ultimately the staged environments you have are there to protect against bugs making it into production. Maybe further automation can make the process faster so that there is not a timing concern going through staged environments.

Comment: Thank you very much Bernie, just a question about the DACBAC/scripts, This requires DACBAC/scripts to be created in SSMS and added into the VS project or to an area where VSTS can collect it, am I correct?

Comment: @TommyBoii Doesn't require any VS project. The script can be either pasted into the task as a parameter or a file accessible to VSTS. DACBAC is an file accessible from VSTS. This could be an artefact from a build or source repo or any other file that can be downloaded during the task sequence. Something like a script in source control is probably the most friendly because you can see changes over time.